# Caching Strategy on load balanced Nodejs Application

Tags: node.js, azure, express, caching, redis

I would like to use Redis to cache the result of an expensive query in order to reduce the loading time to my client. However I have the following questions:

**1. When should I create the cache?**
At the beginning I though when a request come, I should check whether the cache exists/ expired. If exist then return the result from the cache, else fetch the data again and put the result to the cache. However In that way the unlucky client will suffer from the long fetching time.

Then I came up with an idea that create a background/ schedule job to fetch/ update the cache periodically. In that way client will always get the result from the cache, with no chance of the long waiting time. There comes the second question:

**2. How do the background job workout when the application scale out?**
I host the whole application on Azure App Service, with Azure Cache for Redis. Should I use some library to align the background job   i.e. `bull` to serve the purpose? Or If there is a simpler way to archive it?

Comment: Is the data static? If not, how frequently is it updated?

Comment: Its not static. It updates around 5 minutes, and took around 10 seconds for each fetch. I was thinking to set a background job to fetch it per minute.